# Horizontal win detection won't detect win on bottom row on connect 4 game

Tags: java, swing

Right now I am creating a connect 4 game in swing. I did not post all the GUI components since it is not important. The game detects horizontal wins for all rows except the bottom row. Here is the code for the win detection.

```
boolean CheckForWin()
    {
        for (int row = 1; row < gameBoard.length; row++) //Plus 1 is added to prepare for dimension swap.
        { 
            //Player 1 horizontal count
            int max=0;
            //Player 2 horrizontal count
            int max2=0;
            int count_piece=0;
            for(int column=1; column<gameBoard.length; column++)
            {   
                // check for horizontal
                if(row==6)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(count_piece<max || count_piece<max2) 
                {
                    count_piece=max;
                    count_piece=max2;
                }
                if(gameBoard[row][column]=='r')
                {
                    max++;
                }
                else
                {
                    max=0;
                }
                if(gameBoard[row][column]=='b')
                {
                    max2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    max2=0;
                }
                if(max==4 || max2==4)
                {
                    return true;
                }
      // check for vertical
            }               
        }   
      // check for diagonal up
      // check for diagonal down
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: You're gonna have to add a lot more comments explaining what you're doing.  I currently am highly confused, particularly with the if statement that has the OR where you assign count_piece to max and then immediately set it to max2.

Comment: The reason why I assigned countpeice for both maxes is to insure that it only count the horizontal alignment for one player only with the most peices aligned.

Comment: I hope you understand that countpiece will not set itself to the largest max by itself, you're going to have to do a comparison for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming gameboard is an array of arrays?  You are starting rows and columns at 1 in your loops but they are 0 based in java.  Do you also not detect a win in the furthest left column?

You should change your loops to `for int row = 0;...` and `for int column = 0...`

Comment: I have not set up the vertical detection yet and yes gameboard is a 2d array.

Comment: I suspect if you had done the vertical you would also miss one column.

Comment: ill try moving on to the vertical and then come back.

Comment: I'd have mentioned the zero index thing, except for the comment indicating that he had moved the board over due to a "dimension swap."  I wasn't sure what was going on there, so I left that alone and instead tried to fix some of the other stuff he had going on there.

Comment: The dimension swap is for the vertical detection, ignore that for now.

Comment: I figured it out, it was that if statment I had on top with the break command. But i'll still give you a checkmark.